# Use python3.6 instead of 3.4 with Jupyter notebooks

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

My Jupyter notebooks is installed with python3.4 and it is working by default with it, recently i have to switch to python3.6.

How can i set Jupyter notebooks to work with python3.6 instead of 3.4 without removing 3.4 from my system ?

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Answer (score 0):

One way you can do this would be to setup a virtual environment.

[How to setup Virtualenv](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/)

Then once you have it, I'll use virtualenv as example.

You would do:

```
$ cd <directory where notebooks are>
$ virtualenv -p <path to python3.6> venv
$ source venv/bin/activate
$ pip install jupyter
```

Run jupyter notebook and see that you are on python3.6